# Python using a string (with variables) in lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda

I want to use a string of a polynomial in a lambda expression, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. It may not be possible, but if it is I'd love some help!

An example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
f = lambda x: '3*x^3 + 2*x^2 -4*x +8'
```

Assume that I only have access to the polynomial in type str.

Is there something that removes the quotes or a version of eval that works with variables?

Comment: Is it -4^x or -4*x ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to avoid using eval? Otherwise you can just do:

```
x = 2
eq = '3*x^3 + 2*x^2 -4^x +8'
eval(eq.replace('x',str(x)).replace('^','**'))
```

In Python `^` is a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), so it needs to be replaced by the `**` [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html).

Also check out the [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) package.

Comment: As a one-liner: `f = lambda x: eval('3*x^3 + 2*x^2 -4^x +8'.replace('x', str(x)).replace('^', '**'))`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `lambda` you can use [np.polyval](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) from `numpy`

```
In [19]: import numpy as np

In [20]: np.polyval([3,2,-4,8],2)
Out[20]: 32
```

If you meant `4^x` then a quick fix

```
In [21]: np.polyval([3,2,0,-pow(4,2)+8],2)
Out[21]: 24
```

or with lambda

```
f=lambda mylist,x: sum((x**power) * coeff for power, coeff in enumerate(reversed(mylist)))

print f([3,2,-4,8],2)
```